# Show that the field is conservative, and find its associated scalar field.

Tags: vector-fields

A field $\vec{F}(\vec{r})$ is defined as $\displaystyle{\vec{F} = \frac{\vec{r}}{r^n}}$ with $n \neq 0$. Show that the field is conservative, and find its associated scalar field.

I understand the concepts of vector field, my problem starts by solving for $\displaystyle{\vec{F} = \frac{\vec{r}}{r^n}}$. Thanks in advance...